# Non-automatic numbering of mathematical equations in LyX

Tags: equations, numbering, lyx

In my LyX document, I want to number my mathematical equations as I see fit, and not automatically.
 
I looked for information on this question but without success.

So if a LyX user could tell me how, I would be grateful.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx  Not sure about Lyx, but `amsmath` allows the `\tag` command to be used for explicit numbering.

Comment: Close voters: why are you voting to close this question? It's a perfectly well formed question, and LyX questions are on topic. And if you do vote to close it's very helpful to add a comment why.

Comment: I agree with Alan. I think the question is fine. I'll give some advice to defjam just in case they are curious, and perhaps the question would have been better recevied: you could expand on "I looked for information on this question but without success." Where did you look? Did you find some answers that showed how to do it in LaTeX but just not LyX? If so, link to the answers. This does two things: (1) it shows that you put effort into trying to answer your question; and (2) it makes it easy for people who know a lot about LyX---but maybe don't know how to do it in LaTeX---to give an answer.

Answer (score 6):

At the end of a normal displayed equation (added with e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>), type `\tag` and hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. Then type whatever number or text you want.

Comment: Good afternoon, I would like to thank you because you give me the answer to my problem (especially Torbjorn T.). Sincerely. defjam